# sql server return value with pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, return-value, pyodbc

I am trying to run some stored proc with `pyodbc` and get the single return value using following code:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("driver={SQL Server};server=MyServer;database=MyDB;trusted_connection=true") 

cursor = conn.cursor()

SQL_command = """
                DECLARE @ret INT

                EXEC @ret = [dbo].proc_mySP             
                  @group= 0
                , @description =?

                SELECT @ret
              """

cursor.execute(SQL_command, description)
retValue = cursor.fetchall()
```

And the framework of the stored proc is as follows:

```
-- SOME CODE
-- ......
-- EXEC another_sp
-- DECLARE @RET INT
-- SELECT @RET as retValue
-- ......
```

The above sql works fine in sql server, however, when it was called by the above Python code, it gives error messages:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('24000', '[24000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver]Invalid cursor state (0) (SQLNumResultCols)')

May I know what is wrong with my code?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Trying to run multi-statement T-SQL scripts via pyodbc can be problematic. Even though this works fine in SSMS

```sql
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE (retVal INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (retVal) 
        EXEC [dbo].proc_mySP
                @group = 37,
                @description = 'foo';
SELECT retVal FROM @tbl;
```

the following Python code ...

```python
sql = """\
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE (retVal INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (retVal) 
        EXEC [dbo].proc_mySP
                @group = 37,
                @description = ?;
SELECT retVal FROM @tbl;
"""
crsr.execute(sql, ['foo'])
row = crsr.fetchone()
```

... fails with

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.

If the stored procedure returns a single-row result set with a single column then all you need to do is

```python
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=myDb_SQLEXPRESS")
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
sql = """\
EXEC [dbo].proc_mySP
        @group = 37,
        @description = ?;
"""
crsr.execute(sql, ['foo'])
the_result = crsr.fetchone()[0]
print(the_result)
```

Answer (score 4):

I have this error in my own code by adding SET NOCOUNT ON; as the first line of your SQL that you are passing from Python.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("driver={SQL Server};server=MyServer;database=MyDB;trusted_connection=true") 

cursor = conn.cursor()

SQL_command = """
                SET NOCOUNT ON;
                DECLARE @ret INT

                EXEC @ret = [dbo].proc_mySP             
                  @group= 0
                , @description =?

                SELECT @ret
              """

cursor.execute(SQL_command, description)
retValue = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Don't think this answers the question. [SET NOCOUNT ON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx) suppresses `N row(s) affected` messages, it does not impact stored procedure result sets, return codes, or output parameters.

Comment: Actually it does. I am well aware of what it is supposed to, and does do, inside of the SSMS. However, when connecting to MSSQL it from Python and running multiple SQL statements, using that code enables Python to accept the results. You should probably test things before declaring them incorrect as I've encountered and fixed this problem multiple times in multiple languages.

You must set NOCOUNT ON when running multi-line tsql from Python, R, and VBA. Otherwise you will encounter a different, unhelpful, error in each of the three.

Comment: Thanks @Lucas925; this also worked with a sql statement (as opposed to an sp) with a table variable. I know you know that but I am stating this for future visitors.

Answer (score -2):

Just add "SET NOCOUNT ON;" as the first line in a procedure and pyodbc will be able to get the data from a select statement at the end of the procedure.

Comment: Please, provide more details about your solution instead of a single sentence. Where the `SET NOCOUNT ON;` should be included in the Question source code ?